# Is there some image framework for PHP?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, frameworks

MagickWand is not suit, because it doesn't work on simple hosting.

I'm searching for image framework to solve following tasks:
1) Combine images
2) Resize images

I tried to use codeigniter component, but it cannot combine images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are at least two:  [GD](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php), and [ImageMagick](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php) are both quite popular.  GD is well-suited to procedural code, while ImageMagick is well-suited to object-oriented code.

Comment: The CI image library uses either GD or ImageMagick behind the scenes, so you could implement the combining of images in an extension to the CI library. Either way, you'd have to write the code yourself.

Answer (score 1):

I think [GD Library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) is all you need.